# Loop through panda dataframe and extract select column data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe where i was able to extract certains rows based on multiple columns value.

code to extract rows where column "folder == True" and column "depth == 1"

```
folders = df[(df["folder"] == True) & (df['depth'] == 1)]
```

folders dataframe

```
    id                                               path               mtime               ctime  folder  num_files  depth
17   2                           \\fileserver\bckup\admin 2020-07-10 16:36:58 2020-07-10 16:17:33    True       16.0      1
19  20                            \\fileserver\bckup\test 2020-07-10 16:19:33 2020-07-10 16:17:46    True        1.0      1
```

With the folders dataframe, I would like to to select the path and ctime values for each row, and calculate ctime against current date and if it is over X nunber of days, delete the path. I'm having difficulty iterating the dataframe for path and ctime, can you advise?

Thanks

Comment: Define a function. Use `.apply()` method to send every row to that function

Comment: read about .apply() , https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-apply.php, but not confident if i can implement that? Can you  provide example or maybe advise how to extract that into a dictionary( im gettng duplicates)? thx

Comment: Apply is not needed. Convert required column to datetime column and subtract with current date. If delta exceeds n days, filter.

Comment: combine https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html#operations and https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-subset-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-of-a-column/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `df` below is your `folder` dataframe, you can do:

```
# todays date
today = pd.Timestamp('today')

# no. of days
x = 6

df['days_diff'] = (today - df['ctime']).dt.days

# set path to None days_diff > x
m = df['days_diff'].gt(x)
df.loc[m, 'path'] = None

cols = ['path', 'ctime', 'days_diff']
print(df[cols])

                                        path               ctime  days_diff
0                  \\fileserver\bckup\admin  2020-07-10 16:17:33          5
1                   \\fileserver\bckup\test  2020-07-10 16:17:46          5
```

Comment: Thx YOLO, i was able to achieve my goal.